# Meaning of "There as a man, if that he was a man, not that his manhood could be call'd in question" in Byron's Don Juan

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

From Byron's *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Seventh)*:

> **There was a man, if that he was a man,
>
>        Not that his manhood could be call'd in question**,
>   For had he not been Hercules, his span
>        Had been as short in youth as indigestion
>   Made his last illness, when, all worn and wan,
>        He died beneath a tree, as much unblest on
>   The soil of the green province he had wasted,
>   As e'er was locust on the land it blasted.

What is the meaning of the phrase in bold, especially **if that he was a man**?

"If he was anything at all, he was first and foremost a man"? But why then the next line begins with **Not that his manhood could be called in question**?

Comment: Inclusion of the word ***that*** in the first line is an obsolete feature of Chaucerian English. The second line could be seen as a "parenthetical aside" - Byron is suggesting that Hercules might be *more* than a man (a demi-god, perhaps), but he certainly wouldn't want to question his "manliness" (we wouldn't use "manhood" there today, since nowadays it's usually a euphemism for the male genitalia).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think it *was* an euphemism for genitalia in Byron's work because he writes of Count Potyomkin, a lover of Catherine the Great

Comment: 'if that he was' would usually be rendered 'if he actually was' nowadays.

Comment: @CowperKettle: Things like that are open to "Lit Crit interpretation", but I honestly think it's unlikely Byron would have intended any such crude allusions in the context of heroic poetry. It's not exactly a "dirty limerick" style.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - a quote glimpsed earlier in the text: "In Catherine's reign, whom glory still adores, \ As greatest of all sovereigns and whores".

Comment: [Catherine the Great! The great whore of history.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j6TxJVV97A0C&pg=PA387&lpg=PA387&dq=%22Catherine+the+great%22+whore&source=bl&ots=hSDj7-L0Tj&sig=sc0z-v3lGbwJwtFKkQl43Vau4-k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL7vvn6dLYAhXmJ8AKHTcHAfQQ6AEIVzAI#v=onepage&q=%22Catherine%20the%20great%22%20whore&f=false) As Byron would be well aware, but that would hardly license him to wallow in the gutter with [dick jokes.](https://www.buzzfeed.com/pablovaldivia/you-will-laugh-very-hard?utm_term=.phLx5zeXO#.bdNw1W4Vv) (Q: Is having a penis fun? A: It has its ups and downs.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers the author of "There's a whore on my right / For I rhyme best at night / when a c--t is tied close to my inkstand [elision original]" certainly had no great fear of such allusions. I'm inclined to think he wasn't referencing that sense of *manhood* simply because there's no other indication of that meaning in that stanza. I'm also inclined to think he wouldn't be upset by people thinking of that sense, either.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: The earliest instance I can find of [*his manhood stirred*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+manhood+stirred%22) (a pretty unambiguous reference to the penis) is 1875 - half a century after Byron's death. As I said before, Lit Crit interpretation would allow for the "genitalia" allusion, but I think the cited text relates to the *first* part of the relevant OED definition III 4d ***The sexual potency of a man; virility;** (by extension) the male genitals; the penis.* That "by extension" sense probably barely existed (if at all) when Byron was writing.

Comment: @Fumblefingers It does have the air of a Victorian circumlocution. Or at least a first approximation of one.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is less about sexuality than it is about hu**man**ity. The man is being *compared to a locust* in this passage. The implication is that *masculine virility* alone is not enough to arm oneself against *mortality*. Sure, it may have lengthened his life -- but it failed to help him avoid the inevitable end.

The author contrasted the two most common basic meanings of the word, [man](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/man):

> 1. An adult human **male**.
> 2. A **human** being of either sex; a **person**.

Comment: I think this interpretation is correct in conjoining the human sense of "man" with an allusion to the ανηρ sense of manliness and in the "manhood" line. Essentially Byron's thought process seems to be "There was a human being, if indeed he was a human being and not a demigod—not that there could be any doubt, given the events of his life, that he was manly enough. It's a bit of jokey wordplay, as well as (as you say) a comment on the limited powers of even the most extreme masculinity.

Answer (score 1):

It is after all a complex topic, sexuality. Byron is referring to the son of Zeus, and describing him as a man, then immediately retracting the previous statement by implying he is a god, then going on to describe how manly he is. He's basically saying Hercules was more manly than any man.

Now this is the territory where you must be left wanton, for truely, who is to say what constitutes a manly man? It is a rather hot button issue currently.

Essentially, a manly man is said to be one who is muscular, strapping, and large. In truth however a manly man is someone who cries. And is goofy, and kind.